# Crazy hard CSS dilemma

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ajax

I've been trying to make the styling added to this flash message in my application layout work as desired:

```
<div id= "notice"><% flash.each do |key, value| %>
   <%= value %>
<% end %></div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#notice {
    background: #e6efc2;
    color: #264409;
    border-color: #c6d880;
    padding: 0.8em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

Now the problem with this is that the flash message is rendered with ajax, and so the styling is supposed to appear only when the flash message appears. However, this is not the case. A green div appears even when there is no flash message, and this looks rather awkward.

Now I've tried something like this:

```
<div id= "notice"><% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %></div>
```

where I use the `"<%= key%>"` class for styling. I leave the `<div id="notice">` on the outside for the ajax rendering because it doesn't seem to pick up the div within the ruby block. However, the CSS styling does not get rendered with the `"<%= key%>"` class. So it seems like i'm stuck between two bad options:

1. Have an awkward green div in my app at all times that only looks how it should when the flash message is rendered or
2. Not have the awkward green div, but then have no styling for the flash message so that it just looks like some awkward text.

Is there any way that I can get the best of both worlds?

Comment: Is the div empty when there isn't a flash? If there's nothing inside a div it shouldn't render unless you specify height and width.

Comment: Well the div is being rendered and I have not specified height and width. Also, I don't understand "Is the div empty there isn't a flash?"

Comment: Sorry, I meant "'when' there isn't a flash." If the div has no spaces or anything inside it it shouldn't appear. There are probably spaces in it (newlines count as spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share your AJAX that is generating this?

One thing I would try in your situation is using jQuery's [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method to add the flash DIV to the top of the page when the flash message is triggered, and then take it away after some timer.

--EDIT--

Here's a "for instance" example:

Let's just say your ajax call is hitting FoosController#Update, and is sent from the #show action.

In the show view I would have something like:

```
<div class="notices"></div>
```

I would put your flash messages in a partial (makes the ajax code easier), so something like
`views/shared/_flash.html.erb`...

```
<div class="flash"><% flash.each do |key, value| %>
   <%= value %>
<% end %></div>
```

In jQuery + ERB I would write an `update.js.erb` file in the `views/foos/`

```
$('div.notices').append('<%= render 'shared/flash' %>');
```

Then to make it automatically fade out you could include a script (either in the specific view with flash messages or in the application.js file) like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.flash').delay(5000).fadeOut();
});
```

That would make any div.flash fade out and disappear after 5 seconds. Alternatively you could make it go away after click using the jQuery click() method.

I hope that helps.

--EDIT AGAIN--

According to [this railscast](http://media.railscasts.com/videos/043_ajax_with_rjs.mov), to do this with RJS:

In your view create:

```
<div id="notices"></div>
```

In your RJS file do:

```
page.insert_html :bottom, :partial=>'shared/flash'
```

It's still a good idea to put your flash messages in a partial. Be sure and put the flash messages in `div.flash` as described in the first edit, and you should be good to go.

Comment: It's an .rjs file: `page.replace_html :notice, flash[:success]`

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean exactly?

Comment: Ah... unfortunately I don't know anything about RJS. Is there an RJS method that inserts content into a specific DOM element instead of replacing it? If so you can just insert the div you want and remove it after some time, that would solve your problem.

Comment: Ahhh thanks the edit is helpful. So I apply the CSS styling to the flash class, right?

Comment: Yes, you apply the CSS style to the flash class. Do you mean how do you include jQuery on the page? The easiest way is to use the jQuery UJS gem: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs. The long way is to download jQuery and stick it in your public/javascripts, then use `javascript_include_tag()` to load it in your application file. I'd use the gem. Beware, though, the gem will take Prototype out of your app.

Comment: ok, sorry this is probably a noob question but where is the code that I put in my gemfile? I couldn't locate it in the link you provided.

Comment: Umm, you just add the line `gem 'jquery-rails'` to your gemfile. So, I take it you're fairly new to rails, I would strongly encourage you to read Beginning Rails 3 -- that's how I got my start. It only takes a weekend to work through, and when you're done you'll be going 4x faster. http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430224339

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty new. I worked through this tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#top and I didn't find it too bad, but now that I'm on my own, I'm having trouble.

Comment: After adding `gem 'jquery-rails'` to your gemfile you'd also need to run `bundle install` at the command line. See http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler

Comment: Definitely read Beginning Rails 3, front to back, it's phenomenal. Seriously every page you will find yourself going "ooooh, neat! and Oh! now I get it!" it's great :)

Comment: I think I found the RJS solution for you though, BTW. See --EDIT AGAIN-- above.

Comment: yep, I know `bundle install` just didn't know the specific code that had to go into my gem file. Thanks for the recommendation! I'll take a look through it for sure.

Comment: Hey Andrew, I followed your instructions with the jquery but the instance of the flash array is nil, and so I cannot go through it with `each`. Any idea on how I should fix this? If it helps, here's the code: https://github.com/meltzerj/sample_app The ajax involves the micropost controller and view, and the rendering of the flash partial is done in `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Comment: In your controller, try: `format.html { redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'Success' }`. That will send the flash message along with the redirect. As you're doing it now I believe the flash would not persist after the redirect.

Comment: Well, probably it would be good to open a new question. Also, this is the kind of thing that reading through the beginning rails book would probably help a ton with -- there's probably something basic that you're not familiar with but you don't know you're not aware of, so I can't guess what that is and you don't know what it is so there's no way to tell you :)  Open a new question for the flash message issue and that way people can post code in answers instead of comments.

Answer (score 2):

I would setup `display: none;` for the `#notice` box and have this in the jQuery code

`$('#notice').css('display', 'block')`

You can have that right after you fill in the code and before you do the fadeIn, make sure you use callbacks so things don't jump around everywhere.

Comment: this could also be done with $('#notice').hide() and $('#notice').show()

Comment: He's not currently using jQuery though... if anyone has an answer for how to do with with RJS that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can apply the styles with javascript when your ajax request comes in, or have the content of the request be wrapped in a container that has styles unique to it, which is not present on the original page.

Basically, hide the 'green box' until it is populated or send the 'green box' in with the ajax.

Comment: Many ways and many sources, is there an example of the problem to check out, so that we can advise the best way to proceed?

Comment: What do you mean? Didn't I thoroughly explain my problem in the question?

Comment: Ok, one of the things I am saying is take the style out of #notice and put a different div around the notices conditionally if there are notices.

Comment: I tried something like this: `<% unless flash.empty? %> <%end%>` around the `notice` div, but this didn't work, because the ajax couldn't pick up the `#notice`. Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: yea, seems like that should be ok though, does it need to pick it up if it is empty?

Comment: No it doesn't, but it can't pick it up when there **is** a flash message. That's when there is an error.